# Does Finite Liquid work on Minecraft SMP

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I was wondering if DJoslin's Finite Liquid mod for Minecraft is usable on an SMP server.

Do anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mods that change game behavior like this can't run client side.  They *have* to have access to *everything* to be able to change the fundamental properties of your world, like how water works.

Mods like this don't work in SMP unless the creator made a version specifically for SMP.  If so, it must be run on the server, because the clients can't access everything on the server.

I've looked through his thread at the MC forums and on his website.  He makes no mention of an SMP version.  You can try, but I find it highly doubtful that it will work.

Comment: Okay, so I can scratch that one off the list probably. Thanks!